# Monotonic Functions and Uniform Convergence

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, self-learning

The following is a proof from "Heavy-Tail Phenomena" by Resnick (2007). I have some questions about the proof.

1. (2.3) seems to be an identity. The left side the global
   sup over $[a, b]$ and hence should be greater than or equal to the
   right side which is the maximum of local sups. Right?
2. I do not get the last set of inequality. Do we have that $U_0$ is also non-decreasing since $U_n \to U_0$ and $U_n$ in non-decreasing? And how to use (2.2) exactly there? Thank you!
3. By the way, is it OK to post the picture here? Any problem with copyright?

[image]

Comment: Yes there is a problem with copyright. Even though, as far as I'm concerned, copying a short excerpt is harmless (and is often already done by Amazon or Google), I don't think it's legal.

Comment: 1) You are right. 2) Use $|U_n(b_i) - U_0(b_i)| < \epsilon \to U_n(b_i) < U_0(b_i) + \epsilon$ implied by 2.2. Then use the uniform continuity of $U_0$ to get the last $\epsilon$. 3) I would not worry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take an arbitrary $\varepsilon>0$.

$[a,b]$ is compact, so $U_0$ is uniformly continuous. Therefore you can take some points $a=x_0<x_1<\ldots<x_k=b$ such that $\max U_0-\min U_0<\frac\varepsilon2$ in every interval $[x_{i-1},x_i]$.

There is an index $n_0(\varepsilon)$ such that for $n>n_0$ and all $i$, $|U_n(x_i)-U_0(x_i)|<\frac\varepsilon2$. Then for exery $i$ and all $x\in[x_{i-1},x_i|]$, we have
$$
U_n(x) \ge U_n(x_{i-1}) > U_0(x_{i-1})-\frac\varepsilon2 > 
U_0(x) - \varepsilon
$$
and
$$
U_n(x) \le U_n(x_i) < U_0(x_i)+\frac\varepsilon2 < U_0(x) + \varepsilon.
$$

Hence, for arbirary $\varepsilon>0$ there is an index $n_0$ such that for every $n>n_0$ and for all $x\in[a,b]$ it holds that $|U_n(x)-U_0(x)|<\varepsilon$.

Comment: Does the result holds also for monotone decreasing functions? See my question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2751452/sequence-of-decreasing-functions-converging-to-a-continuous-limit-is-the-conver